# Rounded shimmerDrawable (facebook android-shimmer)

Tags: android, android-drawable, shimmer

So, i have drawable from https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android

```
val shimmer = ColorHighlightBuilder()
            .setBaseColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.skeleton_mask))
            .setBaseAlpha(SHIMMERING_BASE_ALPHA)
            .setHighlightAlpha(SHIMMERING_HIGHLIGHT_ALPHA)
            .setHighlightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.skeleton_shimmer))
            .setDuration(SHIMMERING_DURATION)
            .setDirection(Shimmer.Direction.LEFT_TO_RIGHT)
            .setAutoStart(true)
            .build()

val shimmerDrawable = ShimmerDrawable()
shimmerDrawable.setShimmer(shimmer)
```

Problem: this drawable has Rect shape, which is being shimmered.

But i want it to be Rect with rounded corners. Is there any solutions, except contributing to library and modifying ShimmerDrawable ? Maybe some wrapping into another drawable, idk

This library has issue about rounded corners https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android/issues/84 but only solution available is wrapping view holding this drawable with CardView, i do not want this

Comment: It also sound as: How can i add corners to 3rd party drawable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well looking at the source code of [ShimmerDrawable.java](https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android/blob/master/shimmer/src/main/java/com/facebook/shimmer/ShimmerDrawable.java), it's not that hard to implement what you want. There are several things that needs to be changed slightly.

```
// private final Rect mDrawRect = new Rect();
private final RectF mDrawRect = new RectF();

...

// canvas.drawRect(mDrawRect, mShimmerPaint);
canvas.drawRoundRect(mDrawRect, 50f, 50f, mShimmerPaint);
```

And that is it. But you probably want to modify it a little bit more for your own convenience. If so, ignore the above code and follow the following code.

```
// private final Rect mDrawRect = new Rect();
private final RectF mDrawRect = new RectF();

private final float xRadius;
private final float yRadius;

public ShimmerDrawable(final float xRadius, final float yRadius) {
    mShimmerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    this.xRadius = xRadius;
    this.yRadius = yRadius;
}

...

// canvas.drawRect(mDrawRect, mShimmerPaint);
canvas.drawRoundRect(mDrawRect, xRadius, yRadius, mShimmerPaint);
```

Later, you can create a `ShimmerDrawable` with:

- Kotlin

```kotlin
val shimmerDrawable = ShimmerDrawable(50f, 50f)
```

- Java

```java
ShimmerDrawable shimmerDrawable = new ShimmerDrawable(50f, 50f);
```

And to be portable across different screen densities, you might also want to convert the values of `xRadius` and `yRadius` before creating the `ShimmerDrawable`.

```java
private final int dpToPx(final Context context,final float dp)
{
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: doesn't this require for the shimmer library to imported statically? some variables in ShimmerDrawable are private, so you can't extend it

Comment: @jack_the_beast This is for the old version before Facebook completely changed the whole things. Yes, you have to modify the source code. And I don't test the newer version -- I don't think it will worked.